# Check if the I2C target is receiving data from a microcontroller and transmitting back successfully?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, 8051

I have this project where I have to communicate MPR121 touch sensor keyboard with 8051 microcontroller via I2C. I've implemented the code and when I execute it I don't really know whether the target is receiving data or communicating at all with the microcontroller. How can I know it? Here is a piece of code to help you with your answers..

```
org 0000h

    SDA     BIT p3.6
    SCL     BIT p3.7
    IRQ     BIT p3.2
    
    addw    equ 0B4h
    addr    equ 0B5h



i2cinit:
    setb sda
    setb scl
    ret
    
rstart:
    clr scl
    setb sda
    setb scl
    clr sda
    ret

startc:
    setb scl
    clr sda
    clr scl
    ret

stop:
    clr scl
    clr sda
    setb scl
    setb sda
    ret

send:
    mov r7,#08
back:
    clr scl
    rlc a
    mov sda,c
    setb scl
    djnz r7,back
    clr scl
    setb sda
    setb scl
    mov c, sda
    clr scl
    ret

ack:
    clr sda
    setb scl
    clr scl
    setb sda
    ret 
    
nak:
    setb sda
    setb scl
    clr scl
    setb scl
    ret


recv:
    mov r7,#08
back2:
    clr scl
    setb scl
    mov c,sda
    rlc a
    djnz r7,back2
    clr scl
    setb sda
    ret

      ;seinding data
        lcall i2cinit
    lcall startc
    
    mov a, #addw ; master
    lcall send
    
    mov a, #2bh ;register address
    lcall send
    
    mov a, #00h  ;data written in reg
    lcall send
    lcall nak
    lcall stop
    
    
   ret
  
 end
```

Comment: Is the slave supposed to do anything when receiving the data? Some indication? Add some indication to master as well. Use tools such a debugger and oscilloscope.

Comment: Slave is not supposed to do anything, I just want to know if slave is receiving it using maybe ACK and NOTACK as bits when is set or not

Comment: Some oscopes have an I2C data analyzer. Have you tried that out?

Comment: No ill check on that

Comment: be careful with the i2c analyzers on scopes they very often get it wrong, easier to just look at the signals on the scope, you can tell much more than the scope can you can see who is driving the line by the levels, etc...ack in particular

Comment: If a slave is receiving its address it will ACK. You need to release SDA for this.